How to set a shotcut key for copying absolute path in PyCharm's Remote Host window?
I am using Windows 10, PyCharm 2024.1.3 Professional. I want to know how to set a shortcut key for copying absolute path in the Remote Host toolwindow.
I have tried setting shortcut key for copying absolute path in keymap, but it only works in the Project window, does not work in the Remote Host toolwindow.
Are there any ways to solve this problem? It would be very appreciated if you could share your opinions.
The action I want to set shortcut key for:


Seems to be working for me (PhpStorm 2023.3.x though, Windows 10). Windows-based keymap, have not touched the shortcut for this action... 1) https://i.imgur.com/WFuYpjc.png 2) https://i.imgur.com/rN3NPU0.png P.S. Notice that I have a green background in the Remote Host toolwindow -- this indicates that I have set up the path mappings (to match a local file to the web URL AFAIK). Maybe that matters as well?..

you gave me a hint.After I change keymap to Windows key map,there is a shortcut key assigned to this action.Through this, I find the correct action name in the setting. It is under "Plugins ->FTP/SFTP/WebDav Connectivity ->copy Paths".
Thank you for your help

Post your exact steps as an answer then -- this will help other users in a similar situation (a question with an accepted answer is much more visible; + no need to go through the comments etc)

open the setting window of pycharm. follow these steps "keymap -> Plugins -> FTP/SFTP/WebDav Connectivity -> copy Paths " and you can set the shortcut key you like for this action.
